# BPMN - exclusive gateway going out of parallel branch

Tags: bpmn, camunda

[image]

First of all, is that even valid to have an exclusive gateway going out and backward of a parallel path like illustrated ?

If yes, I have some questions on how a business process engine is supposed to handle this.

Scenario steps:

1. Task 2 and Task 3 are active.
2. Task 3 is completed, and the gateway condition make it go back to Task 1.
3. Task 1 is completed (a second time)

Questions:

1. At step 2, what is the state of Task 2 ? Is it aborted or it remains active ?
2. At step 2, is it creating a new instance of Task 1 or it re-opens the existing one ?
3. At step 3 (similar to previous question), does it spawn new tasks 2 and 3 or re-open existing one ? If it spawns new ones, do we now have 2 actives Task2 at the same time ? How is the 'merging' gateway supposed to handle this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Activity instances on the same level of hierarchy are typically independent of each other. In this example, task 2 is still active.
2. Once an activity instance has been completed, it cannot be reopened. In this example, a second instance of task 1 is created.
3. There can be multiple instances of the same activity. Whenever an incoming flow of an activity is signalled, a new instance of that activity is created. Regarding, the merging parallel gateway: The gateway activates when each of the incoming sequence flows is signalled at least once. Activation *consumes* only one such signal per incoming flow. If the sequence flow from task 2 is signalled a second time, that signal will not be consumed. Therefore, the process instance will still be active, with the gateway infinitely waiting for the other sequence flows to be signalled a second time. Your process design is therefore not optimal.

Further reading:

- [BPMN Specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/PDF/)
- [Camunda BPMN 2.0 online reference](https://camunda.org/bpmn/reference)

Comment: Thanks, it really helps. Regarding your comment: Activation consumes only one such signal per incoming flow. If the sequence flow from task 2 is signalled a second time, that signal will not be consumed.    What if after Task 4 I had another exclusive gateway that can redirect to Task 1. Then when Task 2 and 3 are completed a second time the merging gateway would activate again right ? If that is the case then the engine must have some way to differentiate this 'path' from the previous one ?

Comment: Yes, the gateway activates again. Not sure if I understand the last question, but for the gateway it does not matter which signals trigger it. I.e. if the sequence flow from task two has been signalled twice, any of those will be consumed. On a side note: The camunda engine does not behave correctly according to spec here. It triggers a gateway if *any* incoming sequence flows have been signalled as many times as there are incoming sequence flows, regardless *which* sequence flows have been signalled.